The classical symbol for the flat angle
The classical symbol for the flat angle is $\overline\omega$ but with the overline attached to $\omega$.
But how can we achieve this?
Thanks for help

Do you mean $\varpi$?

Magnificent!!! I did not know this command. Thank you very much, and excuse my ignorance....
